# How to update timestamp with timezone field in postgresql using c#

Tags: c#

How to update a postgresql's timestamp with timezone data field with the C# code?

I expect datetime with timezone using codes below:

```
DateTime _now = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
TimeZoneInfo _timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.Time_Zone_Id);
DateTime _new =  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(_now, _timeZoneInfo, _timeZoneInfo);
```

I expect: `2019-02-28 09:24:21.4367+00` before I update a table with this value.

Currently, I get the following error:

> of type time with time zone but expression is of type timestamp without time
>   zone

Comment: `DateTime` has no time zone information, and adding offsets only changes the absolute value. Try `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried

[code]
 DateTimeOffset _dto = new DateTimeOffset(_now,
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.Time_Zone_Id).GetUtcOffset(_now));
[/code]

but now I got:

System.ArgumentException: The UTC Offset of the local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument.
Parameter name: offset

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `DateTimeOffset.Now` (or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, depending on your scenario)? If you actually need a time zone completely different from that, use `.ToOffset`, or `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`.